# How to find the index column in multiindex?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change the first index column to integer type.

ex)0.0->0, 1.0->1 2.0->2 ....

However, I can't search for the first column. As you can see, it's made up of multi-index. plz help me..

I succeeded in approaching a single value using the Pandas grammar. However, I don't know how to change the whole value of first column.

```
                             sum      count
timestamp(hour)  goods       price    price
    0.0            1         1000       40
                   2         200        29
                   3         129        11
                   4         76         5

    1.0            1         1000       40
                   2         200        29
                   3         129        11
                   4         76         5
     .
     .
     .

In[61]   pivot1.index[0][0]
Out[62]  0.0
```

Comment: Show us a part of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could:

```
df.index = df.index.set_levels([df.index.levels[0].astype(int), df.index.levels[1]])
```

But the answer of jezrael is better I guess.

Comment: wow!!! Thank you very much. I solved this problem with your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataFrame.rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) with `level=0`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'col':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'timestamp(hour)':[7,8.0,8,8.0,8,3],
         'goods':list('aaabbb')
}).set_index(['timestamp(hour)','goods'])

print (df)
                       col
timestamp(hour) goods     
7.0             a        4
8.0             a        5
                a        4
                b        5
                b        5
3.0             b        4

df = df.rename(int, level=0)
print (df)
                       col
timestamp(hour) goods     
7               a        4
8               a        5
                a        4
                b        5
                b        5
3               b        4
```

Comment: I'll give it a try.Thank you very much!

Comment: @jayKim - yop, test `df = df.rename(int, level=0)`

Comment: Wow.... so much simplier than `set_level` method in the accepted answer.  +1

Comment: @Scott Boston Thank you.